# Create TypeScript index type whose properties `[key of Y]: Partial<X>`, when each combined with a `default: Partial<X>` property, are not partials

Tags: typescript, partial-classes

Consider the following type definitions in TypeScript:

```
enum Environment {
  Local = 'local',
  Prod = 'prod'
}

type EnvironmentConfig = {
  isCustomerFacing: boolean,
  serverUrl: string
}

type DefaultBaseConfig<T> = {
  default: T
}

type EnvironmentBaseConfig<T> = {
  [key in Environment]: T
}

type BaseConfig<T> = DefaultBaseConfig<T> | EnvironmentBaseConfig<T>;

// const baseConfig: ??? = {
const baseConfig: BaseConfig<Partial<EnvironmentConfig>> = {
  default: {
    isCustomerFacing: false
  },
  local: {
    serverUrl: 'https://local.example.com'
  },
  prod: {
    isCustomerFacing: true
  }
};
```

Notice the object at the end with `const baseConfig: ???` and the `Partial<>` on the next line. What I really want is for `baseConfig` to allow each Environment-keyed property to be a `Partial<EnvironmentConfig>`, and to allow the `default` property to be the same, but also require that the intersection between `default` and *each* environment `local` and `prod` in turn must be a full (not Partial<>) `EnvironmentConfig`, thus fulfilling the requirements of some type along the lines of `BaseConfig`.

In the example case here, `local` would be valid because when combined with `default` it has both properties. But, `prod` would not be valid because no `serverUrl` has been declared between the intersection of `default` and `prod`.

Obviously, at a later time, this config object will be merged conditionally in some code that takes a `BaseConfig` and an `environmentName` and returns an `EnvironmentConfig`, and it will be guaranteed to work at runtime if it is given a static config object that has been inspected by Typescript to comply with the desired constraints.

I have been puzzling away at this for a while and am stuck. I know how to do conditional types and type constraints such as `T extends U ? T : never`, but can't seem to figure out how and where to apply that to this scenario.

How can I achieve this goal?

Here is my best attempt so far, but, of course it doesn't work:

```
type SplitWithDefault<
  TComplete,
  TDefault extends Partial<TComplete>,
  TSplit extends { default: TDefault, [key: string]: Partial<TComplete> }
> = { default: TDefault }
  & { [P in keyof Omit<TSplit, 'default'>]: (TSplit[P] & TDefault) extends TComplete ? TSplit[P] : never };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired `BaseConfig` is really more of a self-referential [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) than a specific type in TypeScript.  That is, given a specific *candidate* type `T`, you can check if it is assignable to a `BaseConfigConstraint<T>` rule, but you'd find it hard/impossible to express "all types that adhere to this rule" in a single TypeScript object type.

In cases like this I usually write a helper identity function that takes a single argument and returns it, but only accepts arguments of a type `T extends BaseConfigConstraint<T>` for a suitable definition of `BaseConfigConstraint<T>`.  Something like this:

```
const asBaseConfig = <T extends
  { default: Partial<EnvironmentConfig> } &
  Record<Environment,
    Partial<EnvironmentConfig> &
    Omit<EnvironmentConfig, keyof T['default']>
  >
>(baseConfig: T) => baseConfig;
```

Here we are saying that `baseConfig` must be of a type `T` with:

- a `default` property of a subtype of `Partial<EnvironmentConfig>`, and
- properties at `Environment` keys of subtypes of both:

  - `Partial<EnvironmentConfig>`, and
  - an object with any properties of `EnvironmentConfig` that are missing from the `default` property of `T`.

In other words, `T` must have keys from `Environment` as well as `"default"`, all of which must have `Partial<EnvironmentConfig>` properties, but any properties missing from the `default` property *must* be present in the `Environment` ones.

Let's see how it works on your example:

```
const baseConfig = asBaseConfig({
  default: {
    isCustomerFacing: false
  },
  local: {
    serverUrl: 'https://local.example.com'
  },
  prod: { // error!
//~~~~ <-- Property 'serverUrl' is missing 
    isCustomerFacing: true,
  }
});
```

This is exactly the error you wanted.  You can fix the error either by adding `serverUrl` to `prod` or to `default`.  So that's good.

Note that having a constraint instead of a type means that any function or type which you were going to give a parameter or a property of type `BaseConfig` will now need to be a *generic* function or type with a type parameter corresponding to this constraint.  This  may or may not be something you're willing to do in your code base.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#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)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems like a reasonable solution and I'm probably going to use it.

Comment: This is almost working just as I need it. Is there a way to allow the `default` to not have to 
 contain all possible properties, such that the environment-keyed config sections can add new properties that aren't in the `default`? Imagine `local` wants to define `clientId: string`, but there is no default for this in the `default` section. Can that be accommodated? If you do answer, please just add code, don't change the existing code, as it is quite instructive.

Comment: Though, I just found an issue which makes this substantially more complicated. If the properties that need to be overridden exist farther down in subproperties of subproperties, the solution in your answer will fail, because it only looks at the first-level properties. I imagine this is *possible*, but will be quite difficult to get right. That's unfortunate. I was hoping!!! My fault for not providing an example that had sub-properties, and which led to the simpler assumption that all properties would be at the top level.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't thinking about subproperty merging.  That would become more complicated.  It might be possible but I'm not sure right now